# QueueClient.Complete(Guid) doesn't seem to be working when queueing another message in a service bus queue triggered function

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues

In Azure WebJobs, in the `OnMessageOptions` class, I'm calling the `QueueClient.Complete(Guid)` method by setting the `AutoComplete` flag to **true** and messages seem to dequeue just fine when running the ProcessQueue function. Active messages count goes down by 1 after successful processing of each message. However, when I want to requeue a message (because it cannot be processed currently) back to the queue that triggers the service bus function, as a new brokered message after a minute, using `BrokeredMessage.ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc`, it seems like it isn't working. Scheduled messages count seems to go up initially. I go back to the queue after a few hours and see active messages in the thousands. The copies are of the same message. What is happening? I'd expect the message to be taken off the queue because of `QueueClient.Complete(Guid)` and the new scheduled message to be its replacement.

**Some detail:**

To send the message I do the following:

```
var queueclient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
queueclient.Send(message);
queueclient.close();
```

Inside the WebJob I created a `ServiceBusConfiguration` object which requires a  `onMessageOptions` object where I set the `AutoComplete=true`. I pass the `ServiceBusConfiguration` object to the `JobHostConfiguration.UserServiceBus`
method.

Inside the WebJob service bus queue triggered function I again do the following to requeue, by first creating a new instance of the brokered message again.

//if not available yet for processing please requeue...

```
var queueclient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
    queueclient.Send(message);
    queueclient.close();
```

I **don't** do the following/use callbacks which is may be why it isn't working?

```
var options = new OnMessageOptions();
options.AutoComplete = false;  // to call complete ourselves
```

**Callback to handle received messages**

```
client.OnMessage(m =>
{

    var clone = m.Clone();
    clone.ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(60);
    client.Send(clone);


    m.Complete();

}, options);
```

Comment: Note that you're using the old Azure Service Bus library. While it's not the cause of your issue, consider using the new client instead ([Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.azure.servicebus)).

Answer (score 2):

> when I want to requeue a message (because it cannot be processed currently) back to the queue that triggers the service bus function, as a new brokered message after a minute, using BrokeredMessage.ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc, it seems like it isn't working

If you fail to process your message, do not re-queue it. Instead, abandon ([with a reason](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/azure-service-bus--abandon-with-reason)) and it will be picked up again.

`BrokeredMessage.ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` is intended to be used for messages added to the queue. When you receive a message, you can complete, dead-letter, defer, or abandon. If you abandon a message, it will be retried, but you can't control when that will happen. If you have no other messages in the queue, it will be retried almost immediately.

Note: when you see a behaviour that you suspect is not right, having a simple repro to share would be very helpful.

Comment: OK but I don't want to dead letter it. I want it to be picked up indefinitely till it gets processed. Is there no way to do that?

Comment: You can abandon. It will be picked up and re-processed again.

Comment: .Abandon does not dead letter it.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.abandon?view=azure-dotnet    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.deadletter?view=azure-dotnet